# python unresolved attribute - HTTPError

Tags: python

using pycharm (python 3) to write a python program,there are part of the program:

```
class  GraphAPI(object):
    ...
    def get_version(self):
        '''Fetch the current version number of the Graph API being used'''
        args = {"access_token":self.access_token}
        try:
            response = self.request(
                "GET",
                FACEBOOK_GRAPH_URL + self.version + "/me",
                params = args,
                timeout = self.timeout,
                proxies = self.proxies
            )
        except requests.HTTPError as e:
            response = json.loads(e.read())
            raise GraphAPIError(response)
```

However, the "e.read()" is in yellow color, when moving mouse on it, it shows:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'read' for class 'HTTPError',This inspection     

detected names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and   

duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases.Top-

level and class-level items are supported better than instance items
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . In this particular case, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

pycharm tells you that it doesn't understand that this "e" of type requests.HTTPError does have a read() method.

So, most likely, you are simply missing the correct import statement. You have to make sure that the "name" requests.HTTPError is known to your IDE.

(and just for the record: pycharm is usually correct about such assignments, so when pycharm gives you an error for that line, your code has in fact a problem and will fail at runtime)